# Choosing only certain children of models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, find, selection, finder

Say I have a model User which has_many Post children.

Obviously I can access the children using something like this:

```
user = User.first
posts = user.posts
```

but how can I pare down those posts to those that meet certain conditions?

```
user = User.first
posts = user.posts
recent_posts = posts.where(:created_at => > (Time.now - 1.day))
```

I'm on Rails 2.3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails2:

```
recent_posts = posts.all(:conditions=> ['created_at > ?', (Time.now - 1.day)])
```

Rails3:

```
recent_posts = posts.where('created_at > ?', (Time.now - 1.day))
```

Comment: Doesn't post.all neglect the fact that it is only the certain user's posts?

Comment: After a small change (which I added to the answer), this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class User
  has_many :posts do
    def recent duration=1.day
      all(:conditions => ["created_at >= ? ", duration.ago])
    end
  end

end
```

Now you can make following calls:

```
user.posts # all posts for user
user.posts.recent # posts since last one day
user.posts.recent(2.days) # posts since last two days
user.posts.recent(30.minutes) # posts since last 30 minutes
```

Comment: This is really useful to know, so I voted you up, but it didn't directly answer my question. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @yaj786, what was your question then? I thought you wanted to get the recent posts declaratively.